# Java Fx File Location Exception

Tags: java, maven, javafx

Hello I am new to JavaFx. I've created a Maven Project for my **JavaFx project**.
I'm trying to load the first .fxml file however I am getting the above exception. I've tried a few things but I just keep going round in circles. Getting the following exception: 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.`

**ControllerClass**

```
public class HomeScreenController extends Application {

    @FXML
    private Button ProjectProp;

    @FXML
    private Button Tech;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("homescreen.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**.fxml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.thales.HomeScreenController">
       <children>
          <Button fx:id="projectProp" layoutX="46.0" layoutY="38.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="145.0" text="Project Properties" />
          <Button fx:id="tech" layoutX="46.0" layoutY="114.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="145.0" text="Technologies" />
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Structure

[image]

Comment: As an aside, it's a bad idea to use the same class as an `Application` subclass and as a controller. I'm pretty sure this is not causing the problem, but it can create a lot of confusion: you end up with two instances of that class, and the `@FXML`-injected fields are only initialized in one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java code and path for the resource look correct, so there is something wrong with your setup and/or build process.

From your screenshot, it looks like you have created a *folder* called `org.thales` in the `src/main/resources` source folder. What you need here is a *package* called `org.thales`. You can check this using a file browser and looking at the build folder (which, by default in Maven, will be `target/classes`). Under there you should have an `org` directory, with a `thales` subdirectory, which should contain all your class files and FXML files. I suspect you will find an `org.thales` directory with the FXML files in there.

Right-click on `src/main/resources` in the left pane in eclipse, and choose "New" and then "Package", and enter `org.thales` for the package name. Then move the FXML files (you can drag and drop them in the left eclipse pane) to the package. That should fix the problem. (You can also clean up by deleting the `org.thales` *folder*, which should now be empty.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tested it straight after you first commented as just a standard Java Project. I'm new to configuring Maven so this has massively helped! It now works :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a forward slash to the file name including the file structure?

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/thales/homescreen.fxml"));
```

I'm not too familiar with the IDE you are using, but I think it looks in resources but if you nest the file you need to specify where to find it. Also looking at my own projects I always have a properties file which resides in the same folder as the fxml for instance my last project went like this

```java
  private static final String LAYOUT_RESOURCE = "imsort.fxml";
  private static final String RESOURCE_BUNDLE = "strings";


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(RESOURCE_BUNDLE);
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(classLoader.getResource(LAYOUT_RESOURCE), bundle);
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setResizable(true);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.show();
    setStageSize(stage, root);
}
```

If you don't have any properties you can create an empty file called "strings.properties" put it in the same location as the .fxml